# SQL Server 2008 Case Sensitivity problem

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server query analyzer raises an error when I type my table names with lower-case letters.

My server and database collations are `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS`.

Despite of it, `Select * from table` raises an error, while `Select * From TABLE` doesn't raise any error.

Where I am wrong? How can I make case-insensitive? I use SQL Server 2008

Comment: What is the exact error please?

Comment: error is Invalid object name 'table'.When i write TABLE,it works

Comment: If you are actually using TABLE as your table name try wrapping it square brackets.  e.g. `Select * From [dbo].[table]`  Table will be a reserved keyword.  You should probably think about changing the name.

Comment: Barry,i can call dbo.TABLE but not dbo.table.My table name is not table,i just wrote for sample.Forexample my table name is LU_CUSTOMERS but select * from dbo.lu_customers doesnt work :(

Comment: Ok,i solved my problem.It is interesting.When i attach existed database,it gives this error.But when i create new database,this error doesnt occur.I can call new database's columns in lower case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give  "**select * from [table]**" a try.  And this is a silly question but is the name of the table, table?

Comment: incredible! I am sure you are right! The guy did name his table "table"! Next time he sould try another word such as "Query", "View" or "Select" and keep us informed!

Comment: no,table name mean LU_CUSTOMERS.it doesnt work select * from [lu_customers] or select * from [LU_CUSTOMERs].if i type even one letter low,it doesnt work.I must execute  select * from LU_CUSTOMERS

Comment: No,Philippe.Many of my table names are turkish therefore i didnt write their names.This case is valid for Northwind database too.I cant call ORDERS as lower letters orders.

Comment: Ok,i solved my problem.It is interesting.When i attach existed database,it gives this error.But when i create new database,this error doesnt occur.I can call new database's columns in lower case

Comment: CCC glad you figured out the issue.  You might want to check out this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/qingsongyao/archive/2009/02/13/introduce-the-turkish-i-issue.aspx It looks like it is kind of inline with the issue your getting.  Sorry for assuming you might be dealing with a table named Table but I've seen people do stuff like that.. so you never know.

Comment: Well I am a little bit disappointed, as I thought I had tomorrow morning's joke ready!

Comment: user505930,u are right.It is my problem.But it s interesting that my db and server collation arent TURKISH_CI_A,they are SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS.I didnt understand why this problem occured.I uninstalled sql server from my pc and installed again,still this problem continues.Tables and columns which dont include I,no case sensitiviy problem but Tables and Columns which include I have such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your server has a case insensitive collation, but each individual database *may* have its own collation. As it happens, this particular database has a case sensitive collation. If not explicitly specified (see [`CREATE DATABASE ... COLLATE ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)) databases inherit the collation of the server *they were originally created on*. Likely this database was created on a server that had case sensitive collation and then attached/restored on your server.

the current database collation can be seen, for each database, in [`sys.databases`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx):

```
select collation_name
from sys.databases
where database_id = db_id('...');
```